# DB update not reflecting in Database

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I am updating a DB table in java code using jpa as follows:
I have tried using transactions (propogated and new one) but it does not work.
I am using postgres sql as the underlying database.

```
while(getCount(Integer.parseInt(year) )>0) {

            List<Tls201Appln> eList = (List<Tls201Appln>) em.createNativeQuery(
                    "select * from Tls201_Appln tls where tls.docdb_family_id in (select b.docdb_family_id from work_table_"+year+"_family_ids b where b.is_processed = 'F' limit 100 )",
                    Tls201Appln.class).getResultList();
            eList.sort((x1, x2)->x1.getEarliestFilingDate().before(x2.getEarliestFilingDate())?1:x1.getEarliestFilingDate().after(x2.getEarliestFilingDate())?-1:0);

            Set<Integer> uniqueDocDBIds = eList.stream().map(x -> 
                x.getDocdbFamilyId()
            ).collect(Collectors.toSet());

            updateTable(uniqueDocDBIds);

            String rssFile = "";
            try {
                rssFile = rssGenerator.generatRSSFromData(eList, year);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            exchange.getIn().setBody(rssFile);
            zipper.writeTozip(exchange);
        }

//      return rssFile;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    private void updateTable(Set<Integer> uniqueDocDBIds) {

        String ids = "";
        for(Integer id : uniqueDocDBIds) {
            ids += ","+id;
        }

        if(ids.length() >=2) {

            ids = ids.substring(1);
            String query = "update work_table_"+year+"_family_ids  set is_processed='T' where docdb_family_id in (" +ids+")";
            int result = em.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate();
            em.flush();
            Logger.getLogger(PatstatService.class).debug("records updated: "+result);
        }
    }

    public long getCount(int year) {


        return  ((Number)em.createNativeQuery(
                "select count(*) from work_table_"+year+"_family_ids  where is_processed='F'").getSingleResult()).longValue();

    }
```

The code runs fine without errors, however the DB table does not get updated:

```
select count(*) from work_table_1996_family_ids where is_processed='T'
```

always returns  0.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: no.. it is not empty.. it has a few million records..

Comment: The call goes through in java code and it even returns the number of records updated. However the same is not reflected on DB table. So when I query the table to process the next cycle there is a always a chance that the same records appear again.

Comment: do you commit the transaction?..

Comment: isn't spring(@Transactional) supposed to take care of that

Comment: dunno - I'm SQL guy, not java - sorry

Comment: Interestingly.. if I move the code for DB to another java class it works.